# Inspect a TFRecordReader entry without launching a Session

Tags: python, tensorflow

Lets assume I write a TFRecords file with MNIST examples (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/convert_to_records.py)
This is done like so:

```
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename)
  for index in range(num_examples):
    image_raw = images[index].tostring()
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'height': _int64_feature(rows),
        'width': _int64_feature(cols),
        'depth': _int64_feature(depth),
        'label': _int64_feature(int(labels[index])),
        'image_raw': _bytes_feature(image_raw)}))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
  writer.close()
```

Then in some other script I load it in. But the only way I have found is to run it as a tensor and extract the data, in which `r` is one record from an iterator `record_iter = tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(db_path)`

```
    with tf.Session() as sess_tmp:
        single_ex = (sess_tmp.run(tf.parse_single_example(r,features={
            'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'depth': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        })))
```

The data can then be retrieved with `single_ex['height']` for example.
However, it seems to me that there must be an easier way. I cannot seem to find a corresponding .proto to retrieve the data. And the data is definately there. here is a dump of `r`:

```
?
?
    image_raw?
?
?&00>a?????????????(??Y??aC\?z??;??\????\e?\i???
                                                ??)L???^
?y????~??a???4??G??<????.M???n???t????VBљ?<???اZ???\?????,I?ņ

depth


label


width


height
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `tf.train.Example.ParseFromString()` can be used to transform the string into a protobuf object:

```
r = ...  # String object from `tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator()`.
example_proto = tf.train.Example()
example_proto.ParseFromString(r)
```

The schema for this protocol buffer can be found in [`tensorflow/core/example/example.proto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/28166c086204c5ca4134086f250469a3802546ea/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto).

Comment: Thanks, no idea why I couldn't find it.